# Catkin_Make Config file Error: ros_control and ros_configuration in Hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what the issue is here.  I have installed everything from ROS Hydro Installation, I have Gazebo 1.9 installed correctly and installed the gazebo_ros_pkg files.

I can roscd to both ros_control and ros_controllers... but I can't seem to make a catkin_pkg that requires these packages?

Here is the error I am getting,

```
Make Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package ros_control.

  Set ros_control_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for ros_control.  The file will have one of the following names:

    ros_controlConfig.cmake
    ros_control-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  baxter_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package ros_controllers.

  Set ros_controllers_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for ros_controllers.  The file will have one of the following names:

    ros_controllersConfig.cmake
    ros_controllers-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  baxter_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

Any ideas as to what would cause this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79861/catkin_make-config-file-error:-ros_control-and-ros_configuration-in-hydro/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2013-09-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2014-02-13**:
did you try:
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I modified the CMakeLists.txt file and it seems to now be able to build with catkin_make.  I have tested that this does work, not sure why this would break initally by specifying required packages.

Modified this Line,

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ros_control ros_controllers)
```

to this,

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS)
```

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) with karma: 325 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rasmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/6846/rasmus/) on 2013-09-27**:
I had the same problem, and this fixed it. But WHY does this happen? Catkin should be able to find ros_control, right? Is it a configuration error from out part?

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2013-09-30**:
Not sure really why REQUIRED COMPONENTS portion in the CMakeLists.txt, I decided to test not using it because I know packages are also linked through package.xml.  I figure there is some sort of linking error, but that is just a hypothesis... haven't really looked into it.

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-10-10**:
I was getting the same error but my /opt/ros/hydro/share/ros_control folder only contains a package.xml file By removing the line from the find_package() I would have thought you're just making the compiler not look for it. You may just need to use the lower packages, ie forget ros_control?

**Comment by [pawel](https://answers.ros.org/users/11261/pawel/) on 2014-01-26**:
Which CMakeList.txt you mean?
I'm getting same error, but this solution is not working, because my CMakeLists does not have line find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ros_control ros_controllers).
Although whole packege is freshly copied from github

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2014-02-13**:
I mean the CMakeLists.txt that is in the package you created using for example; 'catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials ros_control ros_controllers', not the CMakeLists.txt's in your ros_control and ros_controller packages. I'm not sure this is your issue though if your not making a depends package.